# How to stretch PieChartView the entire width and length of the parent View

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I use the following [charts library](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) and have the following custom control:

[image]

But after chart loaded i got the following picture:

[image]

Its obvious that PieChartView has greater sizes than output chart. My question is how to make final chart to occupy entire PieChartView?

Comment: what is the super class of PieChartView?

Comment: Have u tried setting the `contentMode` property?

Comment: You want to remove white inner circle or zoom whole pie chart ?

Comment: piechartview is subclass of imageview? if yes then set it's content mode `scaletofill`

Comment: @Hasya yes i want to zoom whole pie chart

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found a solution.
When configuring PieChartDataSet

```
let set = PieChartDataSet(...)
//configuring
```

and set selectionShift of the set to the zero (selection of the slices will be disabled)

```
set.selectionShift = 0
```

Comment: Brilliant! After fighting with this darn library for 2 hours trying to get it to use the entire view, THIS finally did it! This library could use some documentation for sure! Thanks for this answer.

Comment: I had the exact same problem until I tried this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
PieChartView.setExtraOffsets(left: -20, top: -20, right: -20, bottom: -20)
```

Edited

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var pieChartView: PieChartView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun"]
    let unitsSold = [20.0, 4.0, 6.0, 3.0, 12.0, 16.0]

    setChart(months, values: unitsSold)

}


func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) {

    var dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []

    for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
        let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(value: values[i], xIndex: i)
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
    }

    let pieChartDataSet = PieChartDataSet(yVals: dataEntries, label: "Units Sold")
    let pieChartData = PieChartData(xVals: dataPoints, dataSet: pieChartDataSet)
    pieChartView.data = pieChartData

    pieChartView.setExtraOffsets(left: -50, top: -50, right: -50, bottom: -50)

    var colors: [UIColor] = []

    for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
        let red = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))
        let green = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))
        let blue = Double(arc4random_uniform(256))

        let color = UIColor(red: CGFloat(red/255), green: CGFloat(green/255), blue: CGFloat(blue/255), alpha: 1)
        colors.append(color)
    }

    pieChartDataSet.colors = colors


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

[Download code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7ooURy3zGWKZzNKVnQ2Wl9DVWs/view?usp=sharing)

With - pieChartView.setExtraOffsets(left: -50, top: -50, right: -50, bottom: -50)

And without -  pieChartView.setExtraOffsets(left: -50, top: -50, right: -50, bottom: -50)

Please refer attached screen shots.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this line of code if it helps..

```
pieChartView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
```

Comment: sorry this doesn't helps

Comment: what is the super class of PieChartView? please add some code as well.